# IIS/ASP.NET WebForms: XSS Injection via URL

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, xss

I have an ASP.NET WebForms 4.x application that behaves differently between different servers. On the first (Windows 2012 Server), the application blocks XSS Injection via the URL (e.g. "[https://www.example.com/(A("onerror="alert%601%60"))/Login](https://www.example.com/(A(%22onerror=%22alert%601%60%22))/Login)") whereas on another server (Windows Server 2019) the same application - literally copied from the other server as-is - accepts the injection resulting in an alert box.

Presumably, at some point in the past, either something has been updated on the 2012 server that prevents the XSS behaviour, but that same change has not been made on the newer 2019 server (or possibly, something has been enabled on the 2019 server instead). It is worth noting that if the same application is run on my Windows 10 laptop, the XSS is also ignored so perhaps it is the configuration on the 2019 server that has actually been changed.

I have spent the last couple of days searching for clues, but to no avail. Lots of sites (OWASP for example) describe the problem and provide instruction on how to go about it, but nobody seems to be providing a solution that fits my predicament; I know that there are various tools available for filtering requests and input (AntiXSS for example) but that would not explain why the problem only presents on a single server.

I already have `requireSSL="true"` on my `system.web/authenication/forms` element, both `httpOnlyCookies="true"` and `requireSSL="true"` on the `system.web/authenication/httpCookies` element and have also tried `cookieless="UseCookies"` (and alternately `cookieless="false"`) on the `system.web/sessionState` element - these being the only suggestions that I can find from my searches that supposedly disabled the "cookieless authentication". None has made a difference, though on the 2019 server.

Given that this works correctly on the 2012 server and my Windows 10 laptop, I no longer believe that this is an application issue, but more configuration - possibly of the server itself as the application configuration was copied from the original server along with the application itself.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure how adequate your example is - I guess it's not, webforms engine would not execute anything in a form `Foo/Bar` (at least `....aspx` would be necessary). Anyway, anything that is executed by the runtime is controlled and whether or not a part of the url is copied into the output is then totally controlled by the code. Are you sure it's the same application? Could you give then a better example of an actual url and a code that makes part of the url into the page contents?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls which allows access to .ASPX pages without using the.ASPX extension. And yes, it is definitely the same application without change as I copied it myself.

Comment: How's that possible that a specific segment gets into a page? What response is generated? A generic error message? Your custom error message? An output from a specific page? You seem to lack the number of specific details in your question. You said *the application accepts the injection* but technically, it's not the **application** that handles requests but a specific handler, either one of asp.net handlers or an error handler. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a step towards the diagnosis.

Comment: @WiktorZychla put quite simply, the "(A(%22onerror=%22alert%601%60%22))/" provided within the URL decodes to onerror="alert('1')" and that alert is shown before the page loads.

Comment: I still don't understand how part of the uri would make it into the page. This doesn't happen automatically. If you are not able to provide an example to follow, you possibly won't get any advice.

Comment: Check the version of .NET Framework installed on each server. If a 2019 server has a newer version of .NET installed, some default security settings may have changed.

Comment: @YurongDai thanks, but I have already checked and both have exactly the same version installed - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version = 4.7.03062

Comment: An application prevents XSS injection via URL means that the application implements some defenses to prevent malicious scripts from being injected into URLs and executed. Generally, you can prevent browsers from interpreting malicious scripts by filtering specific characters, encoding URL parameters, and using HTTP response headers. If none of these, perhaps you can consider whether there is some other security software or settings on the server to prevent injection, such as anti-virus software or firewall.